# Can you create/delete custom mdt records from a Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-metadata

I'm creating a flow to help users administer Custom Metadatatype records. No problem reading in the mdt records into a collection variable, and displaying them in a multi-select picklist.

However, i'm unable to access the mdt in a Create/Delete Records elements. Is this not possible (without creating an Apex Action)?

Comment: You cannot do direct update / create / delete with Flow or Apex - you'll need to use other methods described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237089/update-custom-metadata-with-apex-in-my-org).

Comment: Thanks David, I ended up using a similar utility from https://www.sfdcpanther.com/create-update-custom-metadata-using-apex/