# How to update Custom Metadata Type records with JSforce

Tags: custom-metadata, jsforce

I am working on a **node.js** script where now I aim to update a Custom Field of a Custom Metadata Type record.

So far, I have tried few different things, all of them without success:

```
 await connection.metadata.update('CustomMetadata', {
    fullName: 'MyCustomMetadataType.RecordName',
    values: [
      {
        field: 'FiedlName__c',
        value: 'test',
      },
    ],
  });

  await connection
    .sobject('MyCustomMetadataType__mdt')
    .findOne({ DeveloperName: 'RecordName' })
    .update({ FiedlName__c: 'test' });
```

Other operations like read, are working fine. In fact, the avobe methods do not throw any erros, however, after they have been executed, the field valie in the record is not being actually updated.

Any **other "native javascript" approaches** to update CMDT records (for example using cli) **are also welcome**, however, I would prefer not to need to create a XML file definition on the fly in order to deploy it.

Comment: Via Apex: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237089/update-custom-metadata-with-apex-in-my-org

Comment: I know I can do it with apex indeed, but I was looking for an approach more native when working with Javascript other than mixing 2 different programming languages in my logic, if possible

Comment: Fair enough. You might want to edit your question then (_any other approaches_)

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Looking at https://jsforce.github.io/document/#metadata-api, the examples in the doc are different from your code. At the very least, these calls are synchronous in jsforce 1.3 and the arguments are slightly different.

Comment: JSforce has been of course my first resource :) I not only tried the approaches in that documentation, but also others, investigating the full API references themselves: https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/Metadata.html

If there is a way to achieve it with JSforce, it is far from straightforward. I have tried different options for a couple of hours and only decided to post this question as a little "desperate" attempt :P